How to link github with apex using authentication token
I am not able to link the github and apex through authentication token. Can you please help me. The below is my code. I am not able to access the github either the below code gives no result or error when I remove the “when other statement”. and when I give any other public github link I am able to see the content.enter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description here

Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

DECLARE
l_git_code CLOB; gitLocation VARCHAR2(4000) := 'https://github.cerner.com/CDM';
l_access_token VARCHAR2(4000) := 'my_access_token'; -- Replace with your GitHub access token
amt INTEGER := 8000; -- Max bytes to pull per CLOB in Apex
pos INTEGER := 1;
buf VARCHAR2(32767);
len INTEGER;
BEGIN
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Authorization';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'Bearer ' || l_access_token;
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name := 'Accept';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).value := 'application/vnd.github.v3+json';

l_git_code := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
p_url => gitLocation,
p_http_method => 'GET'
);
-- Check if CLOB is empty
IF (DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_git_code) = 0) THEN
HTP.P('Document pulled from GitHub is zero length.');
ELSE
len := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_git_code);
-- Iterate through the length of the CLOB
WHILE pos < len
LOOP
BEGIN
DBMS_LOB.READ(l_git_code, amt, pos, buf);
pos := pos + amt;
-- Output to Apex page
HTP.P(buf);
   EXCEPTION  
       WHEN NO\_DATA\_FOUND THEN  
           l\_git\_code := EMPTY\_CLOB();  
   END;  

END LOOP;
END IF;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
l_git_code := EMPTY_CLOB();
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
END;

Don't post the code in comment. Put it in your post.
